# How to pass a value from a thread to main in c++

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, operating-system

I am a complete beginner in OS. The problem I am having is that I want to receive a value from a thread into the main process. A garbage value is printed in the main. Please elaborate so I can know my mistake.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

void *thread_1(void *arg);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    void *temp;
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL,thread_1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t1,&temp);
    int *num = (int*)temp;
    cout<<"Value in main: "<<*num<<endl;
}

void *thread_1(void *arg)
{
    int number = 5;
    int* value = &number;
    cout<<"Value in thread: "<<*value<<endl;
    pthread_exit((void*)value);
}
```

Comment: could make changes in my code and share it here? I tried but It didn't helped.... same issue :(

Comment: You are signaling out a,pointer to an item on a stack that will not exist by the time the pointer is dereferenced.  Stop doing that and, preferably, stop using join() at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```c
void *thread_1(void *arg)
{
    
    int value = *((int *)arg);
    cout<<"Value in thread: "<<value<<endl;
    int new_val = 345;
    pthread_exit(&new_val );
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int *temp=15;
    void *return_val;
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL,thread_1,(void *)temp);
    pthread_join(t1,&return_val);

    
    cout<<"Value in main: "<<*temp<<endl;
    cout<<"Value from loop: "<<*(int*)return_val<<endl;
}
```

More info: [http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~ericlo/teaching/os/lab/9-PThread/Pass.html](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Eericlo/teaching/os/lab/9-PThread/Pass.html)

Comment: I want to receive a value from a thread into main. you are passing the value from main into the thread....

Comment: @Ibrahim I have made the changes.

Comment: That doe snot compile. You should avoid C style casts it will hide errors. Use the C++ cast to show the errors.

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways to do this:

1. Pass a pointer to an integer as the argument to the thread, and have the thread modify the argument to hold the value you want.
2. Have the thread allocate a value on the heap and return a pointer to that memory. Then clean it up later.

   ```cpp
   #include <iostream>
   #include <pthread.h>

   void *thread_1(void *arg);
   void *thread_2(void *arg);

   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
       int value = 0;
       pthread_t t1;
       pthread_create(&t1, NULL,thread_1, &value);
       pthread_join(t1, NULL);

       std::cout<<"Value in main: "<<value<<std::endl;


       int* value2 = NULL;
       pthread_t t2;
       pthread_create(&t2, NULL,thread_2, NULL);
       pthread_join(t2, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&value2));

       if (value2) {
           std::cout<<"Value in main: "<<*value2<<std::endl;
           delete value2;
       }
   }

   void *thread_1(void *arg)
   {
       int* value = static_cast<int*>(arg);
       *value = 5;

       std::cout<<"Value in thread: "<<*value<<std::endl;
       pthread_exit(NULL);
   }

   void *thread_2(void *arg)
   {
       int* value = new int(10);
       std::cout<<"Value in thread: "<<*value<<std::endl;
       pthread_exit(static_cast<void*>(value));
   }
   ```